# 'Q' object has no attribute 'order_by'-Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I am trying to include a search field inside my profile page. It works for some of the module fields. My problem is when I use order by Attribute (correct me please if I am wrong).

I have a model

```
class employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=(('M','Male'), 
    ('F','Female')),blank=True) 
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    salary = models.CharField(blank = True,max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and query

```
def view_profile(request):
employees = employee.objects.all()
query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    employees = employee.objects.filter(
        Q(last_name__icontains=query)|
        Q(first_name__icontains=query)|
        Q(gender__icontains=query)|
        Q(email__icontains=query)|
        Q(age__icontains=query).order_by('-id')
        ).distinct()
args= {'user':request.user,'employees':employees}
return render(request,'profile.html',args)
```

I am getting the error:

```
'Q' object has no attribute 'order_by'
```

there is another small error I would like to know 
when I search the field on username I am getting this type of error:

```
Q(user__icontains=query)
Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

Please, any advice on how to troubleshoot or any documentation I can read. For any of the above error

Comment: add 'order_by' at end of filter not to Q and user requires instance not string from query

Comment: Thanks for order_by but can't I search specifically on the username in a search field  @HemanthSP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple typo. Parathesis are misplaced. Change to,

```
if query:
    employees = employee.objects.filter(
        Q(last_name__icontains=query) |
        Q(first_name__icontains=query) |
        Q(gender__icontains=query) |
        Q(email__icontains=query) |
        Q(age__icontains=query)).order_by('-id').distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

first error is a simple typo error.

second one is youe problem to fetch data

icontains used for string field not related field

it can write like this:

```
Q(user__in=query)
```

or something like this

```
Q(user__username__icontains=query_string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the query it helped me to add a username to search field.